# How to handle xml from .asmx web service?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, asmx, repository-pattern

First post here. I am developing a relatively simple internal tool using ASP.NET(might end up using MVC 4) for looking up products and editing some data on these products.  I have been told to program against an existing .asmx web service that returns an array of products.

I'm not sure how I sure go about using the xml once I call the web service.  Should I map the xml to a product object? Use proxy web service object? Should I bind directly to a data control(since the user's search could return more than one product, for example)? Repository pattern? I wouldn't be using web services for the data layer if it wasn't already implemented.

Ultimately, after user enters search info, I want to be able to show a list of returned products on the page. The user will then click on the product to go to an edit page for that product. Happy to answer any questions. I just keep going in circles with different ideas, so I thought I would throw this out there and see if you guys could help.

Comment: Are you saying that the XML returned from the webservice call is XML (i.e. the soap response contains XML in the body)?

Comment: Why would you not add a web service reference that will automatically map it to objects?

Comment: A "Service Reference" should be used, actually.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that kind of weird. The web service returns an array of products. The product data is derived from a text field that stores an XML feed, but this data is mapped to a product object before being returned by the web service. I figured it out. I just instantiated the web reference and treated it like any other object, but it wasn't working for me at first. I'm a bit green on web services:) I very much appreciate your feedback though.

Comment: @riffmcgriff: please answer some of the questions that have been posted as comments.

Comment: wow, all kinds of responses after I starting writing that comment! thanks, all.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: How should I handle this question? Should I submit an answer? I just want to make sure to give credit where it's due. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. In fact, I don't know what question you're asking.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I created the question and wasn't sure if I should attempt to close it in some fashion.

Comment: And, you no longer want an answer?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I figured it out, as I mentioned above, although I probably should have been clearer about that. As a first-time poster, I just want to be a responsible member of the community:)

Comment: If you find a solution, then it's good to post it as an answer. That way, you can get rep for it, and others can see your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a Web Reference and instantiated the reference.  It wasn't working for me at first for whatever reason, but I was also a little thrown off because you can't directly add a web reference in Visual Studio 2012.  You have to go to 'Add Service Reference' -> 'Advanced' -> 'Add Web Reference'. Being a 'junior' developer, I am still figuring out which technologies to use, and this had me wondering why we weren't using WCF. That is, however, another topic entirely.

Comment: For the record, you should have used "Add Service Reference" without the "Advanced" use of a web reference, which is a legacy technology.